# Differently colored hyperlinks *within* the toc

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

I would like to change the color of ***some of*** the hyperlinks in the toc.

What I have tried is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{linkcolor=blue}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{Blue}
\section{Blue}

%\hypersetup{linkcolor=red}
%\addtocontents{toc}{\hypersetup{linkcolor=red}}
\section{Red}

\end{document}
```

`\hypersetup{linkcolor=red}` has no effect on the toc, and

`\addtocontents{toc}{\hypersetup{linkcolor=red}}` throws the error *Argument of \KVS@@CommaComma has an extra }*

Comment: `\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\hypersetup{linkcolor=red}}`

Comment: Nice. Thank you very much. Can you provide me a link where I can learn more about `\protect`?

Comment: Here's a link to documentation about `\protect` as an answer. From the LaTeX2e unofficial reference manual: http://latexref.xyz/_005cprotect.html.